# How to vertical center a text with bigger font-size than container in a input in firefox

Tags: firefox, css, icon-fonts

There is a thing in default stylesheet firefox who make : `line-height:normal !important;` for the input.

My text with `font-size:20px;` have a computed line-height of 37px in firefox. My container (the input) have a fixed height of 30px and i can't center my text with padding because content > container and CSS don't allow negative padding.

I use a icon font and this is what i need a big font-size.

No problem with chrome, ie etc ...

Unfortunately I can't replace the  by another html element.

Answer (score 0):

I did a test in my firefox and the line-height rendered was from my code.

I used a simple css code:

```
div{
    line-height:2;
}
```

The jsfiddle for you test in your firefox browser: http://jsfiddle.net/yso6v2po/5/

Did you check the version of your firefox?